# Obtain only a specific sheet from the excel file

Tags: c#, excel, aspose

It is such that I only want to get hold of a certain sheet from my excel file, It has index 2 which is called "TimeLog Converted".

The problem is just: when I need to grab it I also get all the other sheets with when I copy it over a new file. Goal is that I should only have index 2 which is called "TimeLog Converted". There are 3 others as well but I basically do not need to use or work with them.

I get hold of the file fine, but I also get hold of the others as sheet that I do not want to get hold of ,.

```
Worksheet worksheet = sourceWorkbook.Worksheets[2];
        Console.WriteLine(worksheet.Cells.MaxColumn);
        DataTable dataTable = worksheet.Cells.ExportDataTableAsString(0, 0, worksheet.Cells.MaxRow + 1, worksheet.Cells.MaxColumn + 1, true);
        Worksheet destsheet = sourceWorkbook.Worksheets[2];
        Console.WriteLine(destsheet);
        destsheet.Cells.ImportDataTable(dataTable, true, "A1");
```

[Immediate window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GwtUt.png)

And try to make this here:

```
Worksheet worksheet = sourceWorkbook.Worksheets[ConstServices.WorksheetsName];
            Console.WriteLine(worksheet.Cells.MaxColumn);
            DataTable dataTable = worksheet.Cells.ExportDataTableAsString(0, 0, worksheet.Cells.MaxRow + 1, worksheet.Cells.MaxColumn + 1, true);
            Worksheet destsheet = sourceWorkbook.Worksheets[ConstServices.WorksheetsName];
            Console.WriteLine(destsheet);
            destsheet.Cells.ImportDataTable(dataTable, true, "A1");
```

> ConstServices.WorksheetsName = TimeLog Converted

I wish I could grab one and no one else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another reliable way can be: you remove all other sheets except your desired one in the source workbook and then merge the workbook to your other Excel file. Now your final file will contain all existing sheets (from new file) plus your desired sheet from the source(template) workbook. See the sample code segment for your reference:

e.g.

**Sample code:**

```
// Load template and remove all other worksheets except your desired one
string sheetName = "TimeLog Converted";            
Workbook template = new Workbook("e:\\test2\\Template1.xlsx");
var checkIndex = 0;

while (template.Worksheets.Count != 1)
{
     if (template.Worksheets[checkIndex].Name != sheetName)
      {
           template.Worksheets.RemoveAt(checkIndex);
      }
      else
      {
         checkIndex++;                    
      }
                
}
           
// Merge files (copy your desired worksheet from the source file to other workbook)  
Workbook newfile = new Workbook("e:\\test2\\MyFile1.xlsx");
newfile.Combine(template);

// save the final workbook (it will also include your desired worksheet from source workbook)
newfile.Save("e:\\test2\\out1.xlsx");
```

You may also post your queries or issue (samples) in Aspose.Cells [forum](https://forum.aspose.com/c/cells/9), we can help you there.

PS. I am working as Support developer/ Evangelist at Aspose.

Answer (score 0):

I have found this problem as well but using a different library, a possible solution is to find a library method on the workbook called something like `workbook.worksheet[index].visibility` or `workbook.worksheet[index].IsVisible` or something really similar, then if you set that value to false the workbook during the copy to another file will just ignore the sheets that are not visible

Comment: Seems like there is something in the documentation [this](https://apireference.aspose.com/cells/net/aspose.cells/worksheet/properties/visibilitytype)